# What is the meaning of the Spy++ Icons

Tags: windows, icons, spy++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are some items greyed out in Spy++'s Windows view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936283/why-are-some-items-greyed-out-in-spys-windows-view)

Does anyone know what the different icons in Spy++ Window View mean?
Some are gray, others not. I couldn't find out the difference based on the properties Spy++ shows for a window.

[image]

Comment: Grey == Hidden/not ws_visible

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @Alex: I thought that it is ws_visible, but in the windows I checked both Windows hat ws_visible set in the properties. The answer gave me a comment in the link NPE provided: it is also gray if one of the windows in the parent chain is not visible.